# Multi-language Content in Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, multilingual

I just started helping out on a cross-platform mobile app built with cordova & ionic. I'm looking for a way to provide content, i.e. stuff like menu labels, category names, etc. in multiple languages. Of course I could simple put all of them into some js variables and dynamically set them, but I was wondering is there is a more elegant solution.

Sorry if there is some obvious answer, when I searched for it I only found platform (e.g. android) specific answers, but obviously this should be a generic approach.

Cheers & Thanks!

Comment: "I could simple put all of them into some js variables and dynamically set them" what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use multiple languages on cordova, you should have searched in AngularJS !
There is a function called "Translate", which is used like a filter in your HTML and as a function in your JS.
Here is the documentation : https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide
Basically, you have this for example :

```
navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(function (language) {
var applanguage = (language.value).split("-")[0];
            switch (applanguage) {
                case 'fr':
                    appLanguage = 'fr';
                    break;
                case 'de':
                    appLanguage = 'de';
                    break;
                case 'en':
                    appLanguage = 'en';
                    break;
                default:
                    appLanguage = 'fr';
                    break;
            }
        });
```

this is for finding the device's language, but then you have to put a translation.js file in your config folder.

Here is an example file :

```
yourApp.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider){
$translateProvider.translations('en', {
    my_string1: 'Hello',
    my_string2: 'Goodbye',
});
$translateProvider.translations('fr', {
    my_string1: 'Bonjour',
    my_string2: 'Au revoir',
});
```

Finally, here is how you apply it

In HTML :

```
<p>{{my_string1 | translate}}</p>
```

In JS :

```
$translate.instant("no_internet");
```

Good luck, and read the doc if you haven't understood everything i said !

Comment: What way to convert language of full app like english to hindi or any other language ?

Comment: @AnujGupta All of your app's strings must be placed in a translations.js file, and then, you can use the solution I provided

Comment: Is there any other solution like transalation done by google translator Because I can't put string for dynamic data .How could it possible

Comment: @AnujGupta You cannot translate dynamic data, we are talking about multi-language app,

Comment: my requirement is to select app language in hindi ,english chinese etc . I will show one popup at app installtion that choose your language. So how i will perform this ?

Comment: Sorry, but i can't help you !